# Has anyone actually tested laptop battery life under different CPU governors?

Tags: kernel, laptop, cpu-frequency

In theory, switching from the ondemand governor to conservative should save battery life on laptops.

However, I don't think I've *ever* seen any tests done to verify this or show how significant a saving can be made.

Can anyone find a source where such tests have been done?

Comment: You could conduct this test yourself, but I believe the most power cost come from the Monitor.

Comment: I suspect the same but I haven't seen actual figures before.  A lot of sites recommend altering the CPU governor to get more laptop battery life, and my theory is that this is not gonna save you anything significant :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tests done by the folks @ IBM:

[cpufreq tuning results](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716205025/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cpufreq-3/)

They're not specifically testing battery life but should give you an idea about ondemand - versus - conservative power consumption.

Comment: Thanks for that interesting link.  It looks like ondemand and conservative are identical at 0% load and from 50% load to 100% load, while loads from 1% to 49% will benefit by up to ~30 Watts out of an insane ~380 Watts.  This is one seriously power-hungry system with something like 10 times the power usage of a modern laptop.